# VMware vCloud Automation Center giving "Unable to create SSL keystore" message

Tags: vmware-vsphere, certificate

I'm replacing the self-signed certs on a vCAC installation with enterprise signed certificates and the identity server is giving the error "Unable to create SSL keystore" in the gui after we paste in the key and certificate chain.

- vCAC 6.2
- one identity appliance
- one auto application appliance
- one IAAS server (Windows IIS)

I'm following the steps provided in:

- [Setup the Enterprise CA to issue certs with the proper extensions.](http://blogs.vmware.com/consulting/2014/05/vcloud-automation-center-6-certificates-z.html)
- [Generating the certificates for the Identity Appliance](http://www.virtualizationteam.com/cloud/generating-certificates-for-the-identity-appliancevcac-appliance.html)

After Step 5, #10 I get the keystore error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured out how to generate a cert that will work with the identity and application appliance.  In the generating the certificates blog post, in Step 4: Converting the certificates to PEM format, when you convert the pfx to pem format there are different switches used with openssl.  Use `-clcerts` and `-nokeys`

```
openssl pkcs12 -in c:\identity\identity.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out c:\identity\identity.pem

openssl pkcs12 -in c:\identity\auto.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out c:\identity\auto.pem
```

Here's the [link to the vmware vCAC 6.2 documentation](http://pubs.vmware.com/vra-62/index.jsp#com.vmware.vra.install.doc/GUID-8E7A0EBA-FB3D-4243-90BC-AC38F108FB41.html) where I found the info.